# Scaling down high dimensional pandas' data frame data using sklean

Tags: pandas, scikit-learn

I am trying to scale down values in pandas data frame. The problem is that I have 291 dimensions, so scale down the values one by one is time consuming if we are to do it as follows:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
sclaer = StandardScaler()
scaler = sclaer.fit(dataframe['dimension_1'])
dataframe['dimension_1'] = scaler.transform(dataframe['dimension_1'])
```

**Problem:** This is only for one dimension, so how we can do this please for the 291 dimension in one shot?

Comment: I think you mean dimension reduction? Look at PCA for this.

Comment: @yudhiesh. Thank you. No I mean scale down the values using StandardScaler. I am not looking for DR.

Comment: You can pass in a list of the columns that you want to apply scaling to.

Comment: @yudhiesh. Can you please post an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass in a list of the columns that you want to scale instead of individually scaling each column.

```
# convert the columns labelled 0 and 1 to boolean values 
df.replace({0: False, 1: True}, inplace=True)

# make a copy of dataframe
scaled_features = df.copy()

# take the numeric columns i.e. those which are not of type object or bool
col_names = df.dtypes[df.dtypes != 'object'][df.dtypes != 'bool'].index.to_list()
features = scaled_features[col_names]

# Use scaler of choice; here Standard scaler is used
scaler = StandardScaler().fit(features.values)
features = scaler.transform(features.values)

scaled_features[col_names] = features
```

Comment: Thank you. Can I do it without specifying columns names as their names are very long! Or I have to do as you did it please? Again they are 291 columns. So, this does not solve the issue as I don't want to go over 291 by either writing their names or by do it as you did it by putting them in col_names.

Comment: Are they all side by side? Like from column 1 to 100 are the columns that you need? `df.columns.tolist()` will give you all the columns in the dataframe, so you could just filter the ones you do not want from it.

Comment: Yes. They are all arranged in a dataframe one by one. Some columns have 0s and 1s, but that won't effected by standarization I guess? So, I have 291 columns in one data frame if that is your question.

Comment: You wouldn't want to standardize the columns with 0s and 1s as those are binary classes. I added in an updated line that gets all the numeric columns.

Comment: Thank you. So in sklearn it has to go that way by knowing names before scaling them down? There is no automatic way to do it please?

Comment: No I am not aware of that maybe if you used some sort of managed service from AWS they would do it for you or with AutoML.

Comment: You added `df.dtypes != "object"`? What this one is supposed to do please?

Comment: @Abraheem this gets all the numeric columns, columns that have type of `object` are categorical.

Comment: It did not exclude categorical values. I applied it and columns that have only 0s and 1s are still there.

Comment: @Abraheem ok yes need to convert them to categorical columns, are there a lot of them?

Comment: Probably half of them if not more! I counted over 100 columns that have 1s and 0s 100 and stopped.

Comment: @Abraheem ok the updated answer should solve it, I converted the 0 and 1 values to booleans and then filtered to exclude cols of type `bool` and `object`.

Answer (score 1):

I normally use pipeline, since it can do multi-step transformation.

```
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
num_pipeline = Pipeline([('std_scale', StandardScaler())])
transformed_dataframe = num_pipeline.fit_transform(dataframe)
```

If you need to do more for transformation, e.g. fill NA,
you just add in the list (Line 3 of the code).

Note: The above code works, if the datatype of all columns is numeric. If not we need to

1. select only numeric columns
2. pass into the pipeline, then
3. put the result back to the original dataframe.

Here is the code for the 3 steps:

```
num_col = dataframe.dtypes[df.dtypes != 'object'][dataframe.dtypes != 'bool'].index.to_list()
df_num = dataframe[num_col] #1
transformed_df = num_pipeline.fit_transform(dataframe) #2 
dataframe[num_col] = transformed_df #3
```

Comment: Thanks. Should we pass dataframe values or the whole dataframe to fit_transform as this did not work on my end. I got error `ValueError: could not convert string to float: '[01]'`

Comment: That problem may come from null value or some positions are string.

Comment: You are right! I had string values. I removed all of them. So, you did not add how to assign pack the scaled values to dataframe, can you please add that in your code? Also did your code exclude categorical values please?

Comment: I have added the code for exclude object columns.